# Is it ok to create additional column for helping other column to be a PK?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design, normalization, primary-key

Let's say a Person can have more than one nickname. He(she) must enter his(her) nicknames alongside with other details:

Here is the table columns:

> User_Id, Nickame, Age

Of course, for now there is anot any column or columns which are candidate to be a PK(composite or not).

In order to create PK, I have added `Row_Num` column to the table, which will **start from 1 for each user**. I will calculate the `Row_Num` in insert trigger based on the `User_Id`.

For example, table content will look like this:

```
15, 1, Assassin, 18
15, 2, Fighter, 14
15, 3, Gentleman, 5

16, 1, Lady, 5
16, 2, Clever, 15
```

Of course, the Pk will be `UserId` and `Row_Num`.

Could you please tell me is that idea Ok or not? If not, why and what is the better choices?

Is it ok? Or, I must include `ID` column wit autoincrement option?

**UPDATE:**

Let's say user will enter his nicknames in order. And one user can have same nicknames in different ages. And a user can have 3 nicknames in same age. And the firsta nd the last of nickname can be same:

```
15, 1, Assassin, 18
15, 2, Fighter, 18
15, 3, Assassin, 18
```

Comment: You say you have 3 columns, but in your example give 4 columns. So the meanings of columns in your example are not clear. Please correct that.

Comment: IMO you are starting in the wrong end. Assuming (User_Id, Nickame) is a candidate key why bother creating a row_num column?

Comment: @Lennart To tell the truth, I have tried to give some example absed on my situation. But, it seems that I didnt consider all things. I have updated my question.

Comment: @zgguy Please read the question with more attention. I have said that, what if I add `ROw_Num` column to my table and then I give my example/

Comment: @Lennart I will be very happy, if i could explain the problem. If not, I can try to explain it differently.

Comment: From what you describe there are no functional dependencies. You don't mention anything about whether all attributes are unique or not, if not you would have to add some attribute like the one you mention, I would stay away from triggers though

Comment: oracle or sql-server

Comment: Why allow a user to repeat a nickname and age?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Technically, yes, you can add as many columns as you want to made out a primary key, but you have to look at the whole picture. As Mat said in his answer, it looks like you have 2 entities in here, not one: A character and an owner. If so, in my opinion you don't need a PK here at all just like Mat said.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you have two sorts of entities to manage:

- Players (human beings that participate in your game)
- Characters (fictional entities that the players use/manipulate in your game)

Once you look at your problem like that, you could model it easily like this:

- `players` table, with a `player_id` as PK and information about your real users
- `characters` table, with a `character_id` as PK and information about those game entities
- A relation table to map characters to their owners.

(From a practical point of view, the relation table might be extraneous - you could store the owner as a column in the characters table .)

This allows you to use identity columns or sequences for both player and character IDs, and you don't have to worry about tricky triggers for inserts.